# Replicate transformed table erlang mnesia

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia, erlang-shell

I am working on an ejabberd based application.
Currently, I have a server running that has a specific table with records of type say `user_information` in mnesia. However, I modified this record to include additional metadata about the user.
Now, when I try ejabberd clustering with a new machine: I would like to transform records from the old table to the new table.
How do I do this?
Any suggestions/pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/15998244/113848

Comment: yea, that should do it on a single instance. I was wondering if there is a way to handle multiple instances in some way.
thanks for the link.